# Double ajax json and looping alerts var multiple times when clicking on rendered ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, each

I have two ajax json. One for a chat userlist column and the other for the message history of each user. 
When clicking on a $('.member_list ul li') element ... the second ajax sends the value of the li as json to the db and on success the appropriate messages get loaded and appended to $('.messaging-history ul').

But when I have previously clicked on a $('.member_list ul li') element ... I get valSessionID multiple times when clicking on $("#messagetest") depending on how often an $('.member_list ul li') element was clicked on.

How can I prevent this so valSessionID alerts only once when clicking on $("#messagetest")? That's my setup:

```
var valSessionID;   

$.ajax({
    url: "/chat_userlist.php",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",           
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $('.member_list ul').append('<li value="'+data[i].id+'"><div><span><span class="messaging-data-username">'+data[i].username+'</span></span></div></li>');                   
            //var valSessionID;
        }); 
        //var valSessionID; 

        ...     

        $(".member_list ul li").click(function() {
            valSessionID = $(this).attr('value');               
            $.ajax({
                url: "/chat_messaging.php",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: mergedJSONChat,           
                success: function (data) {                          
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $('.messaging-history ul').append('<li><div class="message my-message">'+data[i].message+'</div></li>');    
                    });         
                }                   
            });                 
            $("#messagetest").click(function() {                    
                alert(valSessionID);                
            });                                                                                                 
        });

    }                       
});
```

Comment: Your events should be outside of your ajax call, and you shouldn't have a click event inside another click event

Comment: Can you show how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by putting your events outside your ajax call like so:

```
var valSessionID;   

$.ajax({
    url: "/chat_userlist.php",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",           
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $('.member_list ul').append('<li value="'+data[i].id+'"><div><span><span class="messaging-data-email">'+data[i].username+'</span></span></div></li>');                  
            //var valSessionID;
        }); 
    }                       
}); 

$(".member_list ul li").click(function() {
    valSessionID = $(this).attr('value');               
    $.ajax({
        url: "/chat_messaging.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: mergedJSONChat,           
        success: function (data) {                          
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $('.messaging-history ul').append('<li><div class="message my-message">'+data[i].message+'</div></li>');    
            });         
        }                   
    });                 

});

$("#messagetest").click(function() {                    
    alert(valSessionID);                
});
```

EDIT:

You must use

```
$(document).on('click', '#element', function() {
    //code here
});
```

for dynamically loaded elements, because

```
$('#element').on('click'
```

Will only bind once, so if your element doesn't exist yet it wont work, the $(document) will check all the elements matching every time the event is triggered.

```
var valSessionID;   

$.ajax({
    url: "/chat_userlist.php",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",           
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $('.member_list ul').append('<li value="'+data[i].id+'"><div><span><span class="messaging-data-email">'+data[i].username+'</span></span></div></li>');                  
            //var valSessionID;
        }); 
    }                       
}); 

$(document).on('click', '.member_list ul li', function() {
    valSessionID = $(this).attr('value');               
    $.ajax({
        url: "/chat_messaging.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: mergedJSONChat,           
        success: function (data) {                          
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $('.messaging-history ul').append('<li><div class="message my-message">'+data[i].message+'</div></li>');    
            });         
        }                   
    });                 

});

$(document).on('click', '#messagetest', function() {                    
    alert(valSessionID);                
});
```

Comment: are your ".member_list" elements dynamically loaded from the first ajax call by any chance?

Comment: Great, now it works. And thanks for the explanation ... I wasn't aware of the difference ...